# Trying to output powershell "Add-Computer" command to text file

Tags: powershell

I'm running a .PS1 script as part of a larger script to get computers to join our domain semi-automatically.  The .PS1 is created from variables and ends up looking like this:

add-computer -DomainName ourdomain.com - OUPath "OU=Computers,OU=Somewhere,DC=OURDOMAIN,DC=COM" -Cred OD\syswdg

While this works fine, I would like to be able to output the restult of this to a text file so that I can check if this has worked sccessfully or not before proceeding to do other stuff in the script. Is there any way to get the results of this output to a file? I've tried using the Out-File Cmdlet, the Tee-Object Cmdlet and tried running the joindomain.PS1 from another PS1 like joindomain.ps1 > outputfile.txt and while they all produce a file, it is always empty. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no output when the cmdlet is successful. Use -Passthru and -Verbose if you want to see the output of this cmdlet.